# iMovie doesn't support Graphite appearance?

Tags: macos, imovie

I downloaded iMovie and to my surprise I realized that it didn't support the Graphite appearance option. iMovie's window buttons are colourful. This leads me to believe that iMovie has badly written code. I was wondering if there's something I can do to get that Graphite appearance?

[image: Graphite option]

Answer (score 3):

I believe "that graphite look" you refer to is merely the color scheme that Apple uses for its "Pro" applications to distinguish them from its consumer level applications.

iMovie is a perfectly good (if limited in what it can do) application that can be used quite successfully to edit and finish up home or amateur video projects. If you need some features that iMovie does not offer you can switch to Final Cut Pro or Adobe Premier

Comment: ah is that so? but it's a just colour choice that can be found in the system preferences. https://imgur.com/a/wYdtHpV
all the other apps support it e.g. https://imgur.com/dtIlahJ . so far iMac is the only one that doesn't. even very simple and low budget apps support it so i'm wondering whats up with iMovie being the odd one out

Comment: Apple is famous for its apps not supporting it's own standards. We'll never know *why* but some programs are *special.*

Comment: gotta love Apple 